# What is base in tailwind config used for?

Tags: tailwind-css

I was wondering what could be configured in tailwind config file, I just can not grasp what could be configured in this file, specially the base part.

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

Could anybody elaborate this?

Comment: `@tailwind base;`: basic css that is required. for eg: m-full -> full margin.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `@tailwind` means to insert Tailwind’s directive. Tailwind supports these four directives `base`, `components`, `utilities`, and `screens` styles into your CSS.

**`Base`** injects Tailwind's base styles like inserting any layout
theme etc. Details use of the [base](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles)

```
@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply text-2xl;
  }
  h2 {
    @apply text-xl;
  }
}
```

Similarly, components work for extracting some classes like buttons.
You can go through all this for getting [hints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives)